# Magento2, requirejs-config.js is defined but still Uncaught TypeError is exist

Tags: magento2, requirejs, slider

In requirejs-config.js I have defined the owlcarousel path like below. But still the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function(…)` does not let product slider in home page work? I have deployed the content and cleared the cache as well.

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'owlcarousel': "web/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.js"
    },
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly you need to put your js in **app/code/vendor/module/frontend/web/js**

Secondly you need to put your **requirejs-config.js** in **app/code/vendor/module/frontend**

You dont need to mention **.js** extension at last.

Also you need to write **Vendor_Modulename** while calling js in **requirejs-config.js**

Just pass file name only.

Try below code :

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'owlcarousel': "VendorName_Modulename/js/owl.carousel"
    },
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

put this in your owlcarousal.js top and close it at last -

```
define([
    "jquery"
], function ($) {

/* you owl.carousel.js code goes here */

});;
```

After that run  **setup:di:compile** command and check.

Comment: This call is in child theme, not module. Should I change the path?

Comment: VendorName_Themename/js/owl.carousel or VendorName_Themename/web/js/owl.carousel?

Comment: it contains other files as well, where to place the current /web/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49049/discussion-between-zinat-and-manthan-dave).

Comment: It's crazy, everything is set correct but Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is still there :(

Comment: I found it, your solution + Mommad Mujassam, which one should I have as accepted answer

Comment: Would a DI compile even affect adding JS files? In my experience you only need to delete `var/view_preprocessed`, `pub/static/frontend`, and `pub/static/_requirejs`

Comment: Yes it is , because you are deleting pub/static/_requirejs. and here you are using concept of require js so

Answer (score 1):

You have used `owlCarousel` as reference that is wrong just replace it with your requiredjs

```
var config = {
paths: {
    'owlCarousel': "VendorName_Themename/js/owl.carousel"
},
shim: {
    'owlCarousel': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
```

};

Answer (score 1):

you need to define the **`$`** in **owl.carousel.js**

put the blow code on top

```
define([
    "jquery"
], function ($) {
/* you owl.carousel.js library codes */
});
```

hope this will work

Comment: Do you mean like this <script type="text/javascript">
define([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui"
], function ($) {
    $("#latest_product .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 5000, ...

Comment: any library you are using which is using **jQuery** should be defined as above.. @Zinat